# video conferencing + drawing in flutter

Tags: flutter, video-streaming, drawing

I am totally new to flutter.

I want to build a flutter application where 2 people can communicate with video/voice and each of them should be able to draw on the other persons video screen.

The communication would happen in a split screen where both of them can see their own video and other persons video.
Let's say one person decide to draw a mustache on the other persons face. Both of them would see it on the respective screens.

Is there an existing flutter plugin I can use for this ?

I would appreciate any help you can give me.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to build the same thing with flutter
I researched a lot.
And found some dependency like agora rtc web rtc for flutter.
If you want to develop together then mail me on tushark690@gmail.com